# Utilization of parameters in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I have always used Verilog parameters in the traditional manner, i.e. passing them to a module instantiation to allow different specification to be used. In other words, used to replace text in the HDL code with the given parameter value.

Can I also use it to perform logical calculations?
If I declare the following parameter:
parameter CONST = 100;

As I understand it, the CONST will be of 32 bits (integer).

So can I for example perform bit-wise operations with it:
assign tmp = CONST^net; //net is a 32-bit long wire

Thanks!

Comment: You understand incorrectly. The type of the parameter is defined by the value you assign to it. However, in system verilog you can define parameter type, like `parameter bit[3:0] = 5;`

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. A value parameter declared without an explicit datatype is implicitly the datatype of the value being assigned to it. In your example the value `100` has implicitly a 32-bit signed datatype with a decimal radix.

However, if `CONST` is a module parameter that get overwritten, the datatype of the value overwriting the declared value also overrides the implicit data type.

```
module #(CONST= 100) mod();
endmodule
module top;

mod #(2'b10) m1(); // in this instance CONST is 2 bits(unsigned);
mod #(8'h0F) m2(); // in this instance CONST is 8 bits(unsigned);
```

However if you declared CONST with an explicit datatype, only the value gets overwritten, not the datatype. I strongly recommend this approach.

```
module #(int CONST= 100) mod();
endmodule
module top;

mod #(2'b10) m1(); // in this instance CONST is 32 bits(signed);
mod #(8'h0F) m2(); // in this instance CONST is 32 bits(signed);
```